# All html anchor tags without those contains specific string

Tags: html, regex

I have this html:

```
    <a id='topnavbtn_tutorials' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='w3_open_nav("tutorials")' title='Tutorials'>TUTORIALS <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i><i class='fa fa-caret-up' style='display:none'></i></a><a id='topnavbtn_references' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='w3_open_nav("references")' title='References'>REFERENCES <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i><i class='fa fa-caret-up' style='display:none'></i></a><a id='topnavbtn_examples' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='w3_open_nav("examples")' title='Examples'>EXAMPLES <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i><i class='fa fa-caret-up' style='display:none'></i></a><a href='/forum/default.asp'>FORUM</a></div></div>
<div id='nav_tutorials' class='w3-dropnav w3-light-grey w3-card-2 w3-center'></div>
<div id='nav_references' class='w3-dropnav w3-light-grey w3-card-2 w3-center'></div>
<div id='nav_examples' class='w3-dropnav w3-light-grey w3-card-2 w3-center'></div>
<div id='nav_translate' class='w3-dropnav w3-light-grey w3-card-2 w3-center'></div>
<div id='nav_search' class='w3-dropnav w3-light-grey w3-card-2 w3-center'></div></div>
<div class='w3-row w3-light-grey' id='belowtopnav'>
<div class='w3-col w3-slim' id='leftmenu'>
<div id='leftmenuinner'>
<div class='w3-light-grey' id='leftmenuinnerinner'>
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='close_menu()' class='w3-closebtn w3-hide-large w3-large' style='padding:3px 12px;'>&times;</a>
<h2 class="left"><span class="left_h2">Colors</span> Tutorial</h2>
<a target="_top" href="default.asp">Colors HOME</a>
<a target="_top" href="colors_names.asp">Color Names</a>
```

And I've wrote this regex:

```
<a .*?href=("|').*?\.asp("|').*?>.*?<\/a>
```

**I need to match only:**

1.

```
<a href='/forum/default.asp'>FORUM</a>
```

2.

```
<a target="_top" href="default.asp">Colors HOME</a>
```

3.

```
  <a target="_top" href="colors_names.asp">Color Names</a>
```

**Here are the matches from the current regex (First result is bad)**:

1.

```
<a id='topnavbtn_tutorials' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='w3_open_nav("tutorials")' title='Tutorials'>TUTORIALS <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i><i class='fa fa-caret-up' style='display:none'></i></a><a id='topnavbtn_references' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='w3_open_nav("references")' title='References'>REFERENCES <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i><i class='fa fa-caret-up' style='display:none'></i></a><a id='topnavbtn_examples' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='w3_open_nav("examples")' title='Examples'>EXAMPLES <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i><i class='fa fa-caret-up' style='display:none'></i></a><a href='/forum/default.asp'>FORUM</a>
```

2.

```
<a target="_top" href="default.asp">Colors HOME</a>
```

3.

```
  <a target="_top" href="colors_names.asp">Color Names</a>
```

***Please modify my existing regex.***

Comment: Will you be using this for selecting elements from page?

Comment: @Justinas no. That should be used as server side code

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to work fine:

```
<a.*?href=["']{1}.*?\.asp["']{1}.*?>.*?<\/a>
```

[Working example](https://regex101.com/r/uH2wJ9/2)